# Notation on quantum information notes

Tags: notation, index-notation, quantum-information

I'm currently reading [An Introduction to Quantum Computing, Without the Physics](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.03684.pdf)
 and on page 10 the following notation is used repeatedly

$$\sum_{j:(jB_q)_{k}=0} $$ or
$$\sum_{j:(jB_q)_{k}=1} $$

$jB_q$ is just the notation for the vector containing the binary representation of $j$ on $q$ digits.....  so for example $5B_3 = (1,0,1)$ and really it's probably more accurate to think of it as $|101\rangle$ when using the Dirac notation. The k subscript is just the $k$th entry of the vector, so for example $(5B_3)_2=0$.  So really I don't know what the colon : means in this case, I assume there is some iterating going on... and not really sure why there is a $0$ or $1$ following an equals sign.

Comment: $k$ is the qubit that is being measured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon means "such that", just like when you write a set $\{x \in \Omega : P(x)\}$, etc. In words, in the first case the sum is over the indices $j$ such that $(jB_q)_k$ is $0$ (where $q$ and $k$ are fixed a priori, in the context).